# WPF combo box Image as tooltip

Tags: wpf, image, combobox, tooltip

I am creating a WPF application which contains a combobox.When there is a mouse over on the combo box, suppose the combo contains the strings apple and orange, I need to show the corresponding image as a tooltip.

I got a sample application from the following link.

http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/image-in-tooltip-in-wpf/

I understood the code behind, but there are some doubts in xaml portion.
How can we use the ItemsPanelTemplate? Where I need to place these portion?

I tried the following...

```
<Window>
<Styles...>
</Styles>
       <Grid> 
            <ItemPanelTemplate....>
            </ItemPanelTemplate>
            <Listbox>
            </Listbox>
...

</Window>
```

But I can't.
I am a beginer in WPF.Please help.

Comment: you'll need to indent your code 4 spaces in for it to be visible and highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in stryles for combobox targettype

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate> </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

The other way if you anly want that particular combobox to have the specified style then you can go for

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```